# Transform: perspective(#) on iOS 8 Mobile Safari glitches and hides element

Tags: css, mobile-safari, transform, webkit-perspective

Using animate.css for a project and have hit a major roadblock on iOS8 Mobile Safari.

None of the animations that use perspective are working. This has been identified as a [known issue](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/298) but no solution has been provided.

I've included the specific CSS code below for your reference.

Would greatly appreciate any help with this as I haven't found anything anywhere about this issue.

```
@-webkit-keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }
}

@keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }
}

.flipInX {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -ms-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
  animation-name: flipInX;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since it doesn't change in the animations, try using the property instead of the transform.

```
-webkit-perspective: 400px;
perspective: 400px;
```

so remove from keyframes and put in style rule:

```
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

.flipInX {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -ms-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
  animation-name: flipInX;
  -webkit-perspective: 400px;
  perspective: 400px;
}
```

EDIT:

cant test, but I can keep throwing spaghetti at the wall. Try changing rotate3d to equivalent:

```
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to help unfortunately -- it breaks the animation. Comment and uncomment the CSS on [this pen](http://codepen.io/meetbryce/pen/WbwoWr) to compare the differences.

Comment: Ugh!! lol. they're appreciably different, anyway. it was just a thought. Have you tried removing it entirely?

Comment: Doesn't fix it unfortunately. Miss the days when Apple didn't ship buggy software every 5 minutes!